# Are all PHP security upgrades backported to Ubuntu 12.04 until 2017

Tags: 12.04, updates, security, stable-release-updates

I recently came across an extension to a popular CMS that would not install on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, because PHP version 5.3 reached end of live. I was however under the impression that all security upgrades would be backported into Ubuntu 12.04 until its end of live.

I checked this on the changelog of the package: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.28/changelog
however I see that updates have ended on 28 Oct 2014, whereas many security updates were made to PHP 5.4 since then that I would have expected to be backdated.

On the other hand it may not be feasible to backport from PHP 5.4.

I'm not looking for a way to install the extension, but on advice if Ubuntu 12.04 with all security updates applied is vulnerable to rcent PHp security issues.

Comment: "software component that would not install on an Ubuntu 12.04 server, because PHP version 5.3 reached end of live" - that's a strange reason. How did the software component know this?

Comment: This was an extension to Joomla

Comment: If the extension checks for a minimum version of PHP, then there's nothing much that can be done from Ubuntu's side.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to install the extension, but on advice if Ubuntu 12.04 with all security updates applied is vulnerable to rcent PHp security issues. Its also likely that I can convince the extension developer to make his version detection more sophisticated - if and only if PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 12 is actually secure

Comment: They should be. If not, file a bug on Launchpad that fix X or Y hasn't been backported. I'd edit out that first line, since it is somewhat confusing (how does the component know something reached EOL?), and is not germane to the question.

Comment: The component has an update in 2015 and that update includes a check for PHP version 5.3. As there are no updates to PHP 5.3, how would I assess if a security issue is present in 5.3 that was discovered in 5.4 or 5.5. Clearly the last update in the changelog comes from an issue in PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: I'm no PHP dev, so it's not clear to me how the last update is from an issue in 5.5.9. (CVE-2014-3668 affected multiple versions, CVE-2014-3710 from 5.4.X.) One step would be to look for CVEs associated with those patches.

Comment: Your comments were very useful. Am currently testing https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68594 on both Ubuntu 12 and 14 server and will report bug in Launchpad. Results will form the answers.

Comment: There's a related page to that from Ubuntu-security: http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-8142.html

Comment: Do you want to answer the question then. This seems to clearly answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu security team will backport security fixes, if the version in a supported Ubuntu release is affected. You can keep an eye on this using the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/main.html). For example, a recent CVE ([CVE-2014-8142](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-8142.html)) had Ubuntu 10.04's version of PHP marked as "not-affected". For issues which don't have an associated CVE, you could file a bug on the appropriate Launchpad page, and let the devs decide.